# How to compare two unsorted lists in Matlab?

Tags: matlab

I have two lists of 2-dimensional points given as M x 2 - and N x 2 - matrices, respectively, with M and N possibly being very large.

What is the fastest way to determine how many of them are equal?

Comment: What about `size(intersect(v1,v2,'rows'),1)`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure whether you want to count repetitive entries, but if not you could use `intersect` or some quite intuitive algorithm based on sorting (see below). I would not prefer a nested-loop version...

```
function test_compareVecs()
    %% create some random data
    N = 31415;
    M1 = 100000;
    M2 = 200000;
    vec = rand(N,2);
    v1 = [rand(M1-N,2); vec];
    v2 = [rand(M2-N,2); vec];
    v1 = v1(randperm(M1),:);
    v2 = v2(randperm(M2),:);

    %% intersect
    disp('intersect:');
    tic
    s = size(intersect(v1,v2,'rows'),1);
    toc;
    s

    %% alternative approach
    disp('alternative approach:');
    tic;
    s = compareVecs(v1,v2);
    toc;
    s    
end

function s = compareVecs(v1,v2)
    %% create help vector
    help_vec = [[v1,zeros(size(v1,1),1)]; ...
                [v2,ones(size(v2,1),1)]]; 

    %% sort by first column
    % note: for some reason "sortrows(help_vec,1)" is slower
    hash_vec = help_vec(:,1); % dummy hash
    [~,sidx] = sort(hash_vec);
    help_vec = help_vec(sidx,:);

    %% diff + compare
    help_vec = diff(help_vec);    
    s = sum(help_vec(:,1) == 0 & ...
            help_vec(:,2) == 0 & ...
            help_vec(:,3) ~= 0);
end
```

**Result**

```
intersect:
Elapsed time is 0.145717 seconds.
s = 31415

alternative approach:
Elapsed time is 0.048084 seconds.
s = 31415
```

Answer (score 0):

Compute all pair-wise distances with [`pdist2`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/stats/pdist2.html) and then count pairs with zero distance. If the coordinates are float values, you may want to use a tolerance instead of comparing against zero:

```
%// Data:
M = 10;
N = 8;
listM = randi(10,M,2)-1;
listN = randi(10,N,2)-1;
tol = 1e-6;
%// Distance matrix:
d = pdist2(listM, listN);
%// Count:
count = sum(d(:)<tol);
```

Comment: Sorry to say that, but this is not very convincing. It is even worse than nested loops since it is not only O(n²) in computation time but also on memory! Did you try my data with this approach? Compact code is not always the best answer...

Comment: I agree that this is compact but not memory efficient. Depending on which `M` and `N` the OP uses, it may be a good solution or not

Comment: If you want a compact solution the `intersect` one-liner is the better choice :)

Comment: @matheburg Well thought! I hadn't seen that in your solution

Answer (score 0):

This should work irrespective of the order of the points in each list, or their lengths. It is a hash-table/dictionary solution that should be fast but with memory demand linear with the lengths of the lists. Please, note that the syntax below may not be perfect, but a quick reference to the main data structures mentioned should make corrections trivial.

(1) populate a dictionary-like [containers.Map](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/containers.map-class.html), in a way that the key is a unique function of the points, e.g. `num2str(M(i,1))'-'num2str(M(i,2))`.

(2) Then, go over all elements of the second list, create the key just as in (1) and check if it exists. If it does, set `map(key)=1` else set it to 0. In the end, all the keys consisting of common points will have 1s stored, and the rest will be zeros.

(3) Finalize by summing over the values of the map (something like `sum(map.values())`) which should give you the total number of **unique** intersections among the two sets, irrespective of the order these points appear in each list.

OBS: if you don't want to count just unique intersections but **all repeated points**, in (2), rather than making `map(key)=1`, add 1 to `map(key)`. The rest is the same.

Comment: Hmm... this sounds to me like a bad version of nested-loops. Shouldn't you at least sort your lists before the comparison to reduce the overall complexity to O(nlog(n))? Otherwise your dictionary doesn't make sense to me. And even if you sort it, it is exactly what I am doing in a more efficient way. Am I wrong? Please provide the code to prove your applicability and for evaluation; I am sure I just got something wrong here...